# Open document in edit mode via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, edit

I run the following JavaScript to open an existing document in edit mode:

```
   url = 'https://sp.abc.com/sites/apps/Shared%20Documents/test.docx';
   baseUrl = 'https://sp.abc.com/sites/apps/';
   editDocumentWithProgID2(
         url, 
         '', 
         'SharePoint.OpenDocuments', 
         '0', 
         baseUrl, 
         '0'
   );
```

I get the following error message alert:

```
    "We're sorry, we couldn't find a program to open this document"
```

I can happily open the file in edit mode when using the context menu flyout "EDIT" link.

Any idea why I get this error message?
(BTW: running SP 2013, MDS activated).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean opening the document itself in edit more or opening the document properties in edit mode ?

If you wish to open the properties in edit mode, then just pass the Item ID of document in the query string as below from javascript

http://site/Shared%20Documents/Forms/EditForm.aspx?ID=1

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Link seems broken. That's a good reason why link only answers are frowned upon.